# Does Microsoft Edge support userscripts?

Tags: javascript, browser, userscripts, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

Did Microsoft announce whether Edge supports userscripts? Doesn't matter if via plugins (similar to Greasemonkey in Firefox or Tampermonkey in Chrome) or as an out-of-the-box feature.

Comment: Tampermonkey now available on Edge. Go to https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9NBLGGH5162S. 

Comment: To reopen voters - while this question was closed erroneously (it was not nor has it ever been "opinion-based"), it is now considered off-topic per Meta discussion on questions about "when will X be supported", so it's best to just leave this closed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

April 2016:

### [Windows 10 Build 14291 now supports Extensions in Microsoft Edge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/changelog/desktop/14295/?compareWith=14291)

As promised, Extensions in Edge offer near-perfect parity with Chrome extensions. At a recent Microsoft conference covering Edge, one of the presenters changed *one* line of code in a Chrome extension to make it work perfectly in Edge.

- Note that 14291 is an Insider preview. The current stable release track of Windows 10 is on Build 10586.

---

June/December 2015:

[Not at first, but eventually](http://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/05/06/a-break-from-the-past-part-2-saying-goodbye-to-activex-vbscript-attachevent/).

They will allow userscripts and extensions in a later build to come in [2016](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/10/microsoft-edge-wont-get-chrome-like-extensions-until-2016/), following the initial 29 July 2015 release of Windows 10.

While extension support has been delayed without reason multiple times since Edge and Windows 10 were released, it will be worth the wait, hopefully: Microsoft Edge will support nearly perfect parity with Chrome and Firefox extensions and add-ons; only minimal tweaks will be required for a developer to port their scripts or extensions from those two popular browsers and into Edge.