# What are Edge Supported Plugins

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I know there are some changes in the plugins support in IE11 and Edge.  What plugins are still supported in Edge and what are not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will Microsoft Edge support userscripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580646/will-microsoft-edge-support-userscripts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash and PDF are still supported in Microsoft Edge as of today, whereas Java, ActiveX, Silverlight, Browser Helper Objects (BHOs) are not supported in Edge but still supported in IE11. 
In general, plugins are going away in all modern browsers, and browsers will support all web standards in HTML and CSS.